# Javascript promises in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, promise

In javascript, there is this concept of promises where you can pass a function as a parameter to another function. For example:

```
doSomething(doSomethingElse());
```

I have written a block based code in Objective-C. Example usage of the code is as follows:

```
[MyObject doSomethingWithSuccessHandler:^()
{
    [My object doSomethingMoreWithSuccessHandler:^()
    {
        [myObject saveTheResults];
    }
    failureHandler:^(MYError *myError) 
    {
        [MyObject logError:myError];
    }];
}
failureHandler:^(MYError *myError) 
{
    [MyObject logError:myError];
}];
```

Instead of the way that my block based code is used as shown in the above snippet, I would like it to be used in the following way (like javascript promises):

```
[MyObject doSomethingAndOnSuccess:[myObject doSomethingMoreAndOnSuccess:[myObject saveTheResults] onFailure:[myObject logError] ] onFailure:[myObject logError] ];
```

Is this possible? It's just for the sake of readability of the code as you can see that in the first case there is a lot of pyramid code that I would like to avoid.

Comment: @Cocoadelica, Either you misunderstood my question or I am unable to see the intended solution in the links you provided. For the sake of clearing up the confusion, I have already implemented blocks based code, and I am well aware of block based programming, what I am looking for is passing methods as arguments to other methods like in the last code snippet in the question: [MyObject doSomethingAndOnSuccess:[myObject doSomethingMoreAndOnSuccess:[myObject saveTheResults] onFailure:[myObject logError] ] onFailure:[myObject logError] ];

Comment: ah yes I misread. Apologies :) Am a bit sleepy today.

Comment: Have a look at Bolts by Facrbook and Parse. These will give  you what you want.

Comment: `doSomething(doSomethingElse());` simply calls `doSomethingElse` with no arguments, then passes the result to `doSomething`. There are no "promises" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Bolts by Facebook and Parse.

These will give you what you are looking for.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/01/30/let-s-bolt/

You can get it as a Cocoapod too to install it easily.

Answer (score 1):

What you're passing still needs to be blocks rather than method calls but the `typedef` suggestion from the link in comments can make things clearer.

E.g.:

```
typedef void (^FailureBlock)(NSError *);
typedef void (^SuccessBlock)();

- (void)startsHere
{
    FailureBlock f = ^(NSError *myError){
        [self logError:myError];
    };
    SuccessBlock s2 = ^(){
        [self saveTheResults];
    };
    SuccessBlock s1 = ^(){
        [self doSomethingMoreWithSuccessHandler:s2
                    failureHandler:f];
    };

    [self doSomethingWithSuccessHandler:s1
            failureHandler:f];
}
```

Comment: This would save me from the pyramid code but then I would have to declare those blocks as variables which in turn results in more code. Although in scenarios where I have a few block based methods, this solution would really be handy but I have a few hundred block based methods in my project where this solutions would not be suitable.

Comment: I suppose it depends on your preferences.  More code can be bad but hard-to-unravel nesting levels can be worse.  [shrug]